# React-Native warning cannot update on unmounted component | useNetInfo hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hello i have been facing this warning issue regarding using `useNetInfo` hook to check for change in network connection. the code works however it tries to update state somewhere where the component is unmounted. Any ideas how to solve this

code:

```
export default function RenderData(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({loading: true});
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);
  const netInfo  = useNetInfo();

const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
      if(value !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(value)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      return null
    }
  }
  async function doJob(country)
  {
    setCountry(country) // setting country 
    const res = await ProcessData(country); // function to process data
    res ? setData(Products) : setData(null)
    setState({loading:false})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSettingsAndUpdate = async () => {
      const settings = await getData()
      if (settings) { //if settings were fetched correctly
        doJob(settings.store_country.label)
      } else {
        doJob("United States")
      }
    }

    fetchSettingsAndUpdate()

  }, []);

  // if not connected
  if (!netInfo.isConnected)
  {
    return(<ConnectionOffline/>)
  } else {

  // return actual data
  return (
     { state.loading ? //show loading : 
      !data ? //error no data was fetched 
      : //show data 
     }  
  )
```

**Tried solution which didn't work:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    .
    .
    .
    if (!isCancelled)
        fetchSettingsAndUpdate()
    
    return () => {
      isCancelled = true;
    };
  }, []);
```

Trace:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method, 
    in RecyclerListView (at EbayDealsList.js:45)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (at EbayDealsList.js:44)
    in SearchMainList (at DealsProductList.js:197)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (at DealsProductList.js:183)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (created by View)
    in View (at DealsProductList.js:147)
```

**Where it occurs i guess:**

```
export function SearchMainList ({Products}) {
 
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasScrolled, setScroll] = useState(false);
  const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = useState(new DataProvider((r1,r2)=>r1!=r2).cloneWithRows(Products));

  const renderItem = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <View flex>
      <Animatable.View key={index} duration={500} animation={"fadeInUp"} easing="ease-in-out" useNativeDriver={true} style={{flex :1 }}>
          {item}
      <View style={{ width: RFPercentage(18), alignSelf:"center"}}>
        <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.black}}/>
      </View>
      </Animatable.View>
      </View>           
    );
  }
  const ROW_RENDERER = (type,data, index) => {return renderItem(data, index)}
  const onScroll = () => {setScroll(true)}
  const LAYOUT_PROVIDER = new LayoutProvider( i => {return 1}, (type,dim)=>{dim.width=SCREEN_WIDTH/2- 0.0001; dim.height= RFPercentage(60);})
  const LoadingFooter = () => {return (<View style={{alignItems:'center', alignContent:'center', paddingTop:10, marginBottom:5}}><Flow color={Colors.blue30}></Flow></View>)}
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    if(!hasScrolled){ return null;}
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    
    <View flex>
      <RecyclerListView
        style={{flex:1, flexGrow:1, alignContent: "stretch"}}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={LAYOUT_PROVIDER}
        rowRenderer={ROW_RENDERER}
        renderFooter={Loading ? LoadingFooter : null}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
        optimizeForInsertDeleteAnimations={true}
        > 
      </RecyclerListView> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I cant find any problem in your code, I think this problem is related to some other component

Comment: commenting `fetchSettingsAndUpdate()` doesn't produce the issue. I cannot find where the problem is

Comment: try to give await to `doJob`

Comment: can u provide the exact error message. you may be climbing up the wrong tree.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial edited the post with the trace

Comment: Good that you look at the trace, now we identify the problem, and it's not a problem with your useEffect, but RecylerListView of Flipkart.

Comment: And this is a known problem, with quite a few people facing the same issues and no fix yet.

Comment: is there any github issue posted regarding this on their repo? I tried looking there but didn't find anything

Comment: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview/issues/250

Comment: my feel is it has got to do with onScroll={onScroll} . You may try to create a variable outside the component, the onScroll = () =>  { scrollVariable = true } , then in your handleLoadMore, use scrollVariable to check instead of hasScrolled. You may give it a try to see if it works.

Comment: nah, I tried to comment all other states and their methods and still didn't work. I think it's an internal memory leak :(

Comment: I think it may be related to `useNetInfo`. Having the same issue in a component that only uses this hook.